# differential linear equation of order one $(2xy+x^2+x^4)\,dx-(1+x^2)\,dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to solve it. Should be linear equation of order one since I am passing through this chapter, but I can't put into the form of $$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$

Here is the equation: $$(2xy+x^2+x^4)\,dx-(1+x^2)\,dy=0$$

It is not exact since partial derivatives are not equal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They are equal though.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla, there is a minus right before the 2nd bracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it into the form you requested:
$$
-(1+x^2) \,dy + (2xy + x^2 + x^4) \,dx = 0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2xy + x^2 + x^4}{1+x^2} = 0 \\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx} + \left(-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) y = \frac{x^2 + x^4}{1+x^2}\\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx} + \left(-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) y = x^2
$$

Comment: Beat me by a minute, and with derivation too. ;) +1

Comment: Thank you! It was pretty easy, donno how I couldn't figure it out by myself

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

---

We can write your equation as
$y' - \frac{2xy}{x^2+1} = x^2$

Answer (score 2):

$$(2xy+x^2+x^4)\,dx−(1+x^2)\,dy=0\\
(1+x^2) \frac {dy}{dx} = (2xy+x^2+x^4)\\
y' - \frac {2x}{1+x^2} y = x^2$$

Integrating factor

$$e^{\int \frac {-2x}{1+x^2}} = e^{-\ln(1+x^2)} = \frac {1} {(1+x^2)}$$

$$\frac {1}{1+x^2}y = \int \frac {x^2}{1+x^2}\\
\frac {1}{1+x^2}y = x - \arctan x + C\\
y = x^3 + x - (1+x^2)\arctan x + C(1+x^2)$$